# Queue-like datastructure that is readable from anywhere

Tags: data-structures, game-maker

I'm working on a game in Yoyo Game Maker where I have items moving along conveyor belts. As the items only move in one direction, I thought it would make most sense to use a queue or queue-like data structure to store the items. However, to be able to render the items, I need to be able to read all of them at any point in the queue, not just the head or tail.

```
     [[a] [b] [c] [d]]
             |
             V

a <- [[ ] [b] [c] [d]] <- e
             |
             V

     [[b] [c] [d] [e]]
       |   |   |   |
       V   V   V   V

       b   c   d   e
```

I could simply use an array that manually moves all its values forward by one slot every turn (using a for loop), but somehow that seems inefficient, laggy, or at the very least, bad form. My programming instincts recoil at the thought of using such a system, anyway.

Is this a correct assumption to make? Is an array really the best way of implementing a structure like this? Should I even be worried about efficiency, or are the differences in this case negligible?

Some advice or examples (in any programming language) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

Comment: @jbapple This would work perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It might "seem" inefficient to use an array, but it most likely won't be. Take into consideration how many items will actually be on the conveyor belt at any single time. If you want quick random access to any index in a data structure, you must use an array, a DS List or a DS Grid(wouldn't make sense here, tough).

Using a DS List, you can use `ds_list_delete(your_list, 0)` to 'dequeue', much like a DS Queue, and `ds_list_insert(your_list, 0, value)` to 'enqueue' an item.

Iterating through the list is then very simple:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < ds_list_size( your_list ); i++ ) {
   var item = your_list[|i];
}
```

It might also be relevant to add, that, in a game I'm working on, objects are build using components, which basically means that all of the enemies, the player, and such have a for-loop in their Step events to iterate through and update all components if need be. At most I have about 80 such objects in the game at any time and performance hasn't been a problem yet.

You should always first try to get a **working** solution, then testing it in conditions specific to your game: eg. if you are going to need a 100 items in the structure, try that, and if the performance is not satisfactory, only then optimize.

Answer (score -4):

I had made a game in game maker which had a similar requirement. If you know about the frog game it had some woods floating on a river.

**Movement:** For that, I had created some number of the wood object which moves in the particular direction. when frog collides with any one of them he/she starts to float in that direction. Also, if it goes out if window in one direction I would place it back at the other side of window.

**Picking:** I think to pick up one of the item, You will need to define the collision inside each object. After collision you can define you next steps.

Comment: I'm looking for a data structure, not an object-based collision implementation. The objects I'm using don't and won't have physics properties, either.

Comment: I am not clear about how your pick up process work but if you want to pick an object from conveyor belt this approach would work.